# Porting XOR encryption code to PHP

Tags: c++, xor

I usually find my answer here somewhere, but I've been unable to find the solution from the existing questions.  I apologize if I misssed an answer elsewhere..

This is my C++ code :

```
    char key[4] = "abc";

for (int temp = 0; temp < original.size(); temp++){
    encrypted += original[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 255;
}
cout << int(key) << endl;
cout << "Encrypted data = " << encrypted << endl;

for (int temp = 0; temp < original.size(); temp++){
    unencrypted += encrypted[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 255;
}

cout << "Unencrypted data = " << unencrypted << endl;
```

Which returns a long string of random characters (e.g. ♧).

And my attempt at translating, as to my understanding, the XOR encryption to PHP:

```
<?php
$input = "ONEWORD";
$encrypted = "";
$unencrypted = "";

$key = "abc";

$ascii = NULL;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
{ 
$ascii += ord($string[$i]); 
}


for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($input); $i++)
{
    $encrypted+= $input[$i] ^ ($ascii + $i) % 255;
}
echo($encrypted);
echo(ord($key));

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($input); $i++)
{
    $unencrypted+= $encrypted[$i] ^ ($ascii + $i) % 255;
}

echo($unencrypted);
?>
```

While this returns a simple 0970.
I'm not quite sure where I went wrong, can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Not for nothing but this is incredibly insecure "encryption". The only time you should be xor'ing like this is if you're using one-time pads and even then it's easy to screw up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your C++ code is bogus:

```
    encrypted += original[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 255;
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  `int(key)` casts `key` to `int`.  In this context `key` will decay to a pointer, so you're not actually getting the key at all, you're getting an integer representation of the pointer to the key.

What you likely want is this:

```
    encrypted += char(original[temp] ^ key[temp % 3]);
```

That will XOR the first character of the string with the first character of the key, the second character of the string with the second character of the key, and third character of the string with the third character of the key.  Thereafter, it'll cycle through the three characters in the key, applying them to each character of the input in-turn.

You need to make a similar change to your decryption code:

```
    unencrypted += char(encrypted[temp] ^ key[temp % 3]);
```

In PHP, to work with individual character values, you need to use the `ord` operator to convert the characters to integers, and the `chr` operator to convert the integers back to characters.

```
    $encrypted += chr( ord( $input[$i] ) ^ ord( $key[$i % 3] ) );
```

And likewise for decryption:

```
    $decrypted += chr( ord( $encrypted[$i] ) ^ ord( $key[$i % 3] ) );
```

Comment: Good intuition.  I just went on what the code did, figuring that at least one of the programs wasn't completely broken.  But yeah, it does look like this is how they intended to use the key.

Comment: Thank you!! Your explanation helped me finish, got it working with a major overhaul of how I did the computing, thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, your C++ code....**

`int(key)` is probably not doing what you expected.  It's demoting the `key` array to a pointer and converting the pointer value to an integer.  Perhaps you meant to do `int(*(int*)key)`.

If you actually intended it to work like the code you wrote in PHP, then you'll have to modify the `key` calculation:

```
int keyval = 0;
for( unsigned char *p = key; *p; p++ ) keyval += *p;
```

It's not a very robust key, however.  It will be the same value regardless of what order the key's characters appear.

**Now to the PHP.**

You should use `ord` to get the character value, then do the calculation, then use `chr` to convert back to a character before appending to your string:

```
$encrypted += chr( ord($input[$i]) ^ ($ascii + $i) % 255 );
```

One final observation...  In both your code examples, I wonder if you meant to modulo by `256`, not `255`.